# Remove /var partition and replace it with /var into / (root) partition

Tags: partition, system-installation

I accidentaly created a `/var` partition and I'd like to get rid of it. Is it possible to remove this partition and use the `/` partition to contain `/var` *without* reinstalling the OS or do I have to repartition my harddrive and reinstall everything?

In the latter case is there something I can do to reinstall the already installed updates/programs automatically in the new system or do I have to list everything I add to the system and manually reinstall it?
My `/home` is on a separated partition so probably it could be reused by the new installation, even though I care much more for what I installed into `/`.

The OS is Kubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can boot the machine with a live CD OS. This will allow you to move `/var` without corrupting the OS.
I have done this in the other direction with `/tmp`, `/var`, `/opt`, and `/usr` on a SLES install. I think it would work on others distros.

1. Boot the live CD
2. Mount the old `/var` partition in `/mnt/var`
3. Mount the real root directory in `/mnt/root`
4. Correct `/mnt/root/etc/fstab`
5. Remove the old mount point with `rmdir /mnt/root/var`
6. Run a `cp -a /mnt/var /mnt/root/var`
7. Boot the real OS

Comment: You will still have the partition that was `/var` but you can use a partition manager to fix that

Comment: Could you explain how to correct `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: in `/mnt/root/etc/fstab` (before you reboot), remove the line that looks similar to `/dev/sdb1  /var`

Comment: I don't have any line that starts with `/dev/sd*` but I have a line that starts with  `UUID=5ebc2009-3089-4f5b-ac93-d8d4738913b3 /var            ext4    defaults` which I believe refers to the `/var` partition. So I simply remove this without modifying anything else?

Comment: yes, you can remove that line after you've copied the /var partion over to the root partition. Then reboot.

Comment: True. The UUID is a link to the device the same way `/dev/sdb1` is.

Comment: I think the recipe above won't work without an extra step. Inside `/mnt/root` there will be a `var` directory to serve as a mountpoint for the /var partition. Presumably it will be empty. It needs to be deleted before step 5, else the `cp` command will copy the `/mnt/var` directory *into* `/mnt/root/var/`, rather than making a copy of it *as* `/mnt/root/var`, as desired. (I suggested an edit to this effect, but it was rejected.)

Comment: @dubiousjim: sounds right to me, I added a step.

Comment: Alas, I tried this before reading. I can confirm that it happens exactly what @dubiousjim said. If you reboot then the system boots, but you can not login into the GUI. When logging in into tty1 you get some errors about stuff from `/etc` that can't create directories in `/var`.

Answer (score 2):

[Yuugian's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55706/9382) is definitely the safe and proper way to go. But for some people, it might be good to know that you can actually do that without even shutting down your running system. You can treat this answer as a training or last resort in situations where booting from a liveCD is not an option.

***Disclaimer:*** This procedure is not recommended for beginner users. If you don't put enough attention to step 1, your system might crash while you perform next steps and you can experience unexpected behaviour of various applications after reboot. Before you attempt this, you should check that you're familiar with [`/var` description on tldp](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/var.html) and your distribution-specific deviations from that.

1. **Close programs that have open files under `/var`**. Start by switchin to console (one of the "real" ttys) and shutting down the X server, as well as the Desktop Manager (kdm/gdm/lightdm/...), if you use one. *If you don't know how to do that or what it means, do NOT continue - chances that you might break you system are too high, and there are just too many possibilities to cover in a step-by-step procedure here - sorry!*

   Use `lsof` or `fuser` to find remaining programs that have files open under `/var`. Notice that if a program was started as/by a system service, it is always better to stop the service, rather than killing the task. If there are some programs/services too stubborn to deal with this way, you might also try switching to single-user mode (init level 1) - if that is acceptable for you. In most cases it would be OK to have a few(!) files still open under `/var` - for instance the pid files under `/var/run`, in case your system uses that location.
2. **Mount your root partition (for the second time).** Simply choose any empty directory as a temporary mount point for that - I'll use `/mnt/tmp` as an example. Usually the `mount` command (without parameters) will not display the real device name behind your root partition, you will need to check which one is it (unless you know for sure). You can usually get the information either from `lsblk` (if you have it on your system), or bootloader configuration, or by `cat /proc/cmdline`, or by identifying the partition by size reported by `fdisk`.
3. **Copy `/var` contents.** Once you've found the partition and mounted it, copy the contents of `/var` to your rootfs (mounted in the new location), using `cp -ad`, such as: `cp -ad /var /mnt/tmp/`. Note: if your distro still manages `/var/run` and `/var/lock` directories instead of recently introduced `/run/`, you should skip the contents of these two directories. If *extglob* is enabled in your shell, you can do that using `cp -ad /var/!(run|lock) /mnt/tmp/var/` - or use `cpio` instead. Just to create the two directories under `/mnt/tmp/var/` and set their permissions properly after copying.
4. **Remove old `/var` entry in `fstab`.** The safe way is to comment it out, of course.
5. **Reboot**

Comment: The offline or single-user mode way is safest - it's only worth trying to attempt a live changeover if minimizing downtime is important.

Answer (score -1):

Under the root:

```
cp -rf /var /var-new && umount /var && mv /var /var-old && mv /var-new /var
```

afterwards remove or comment out /var mountpoint from /etc/fstab and reboot

Comment: I strongly doubt this works. At least reading @rozcietrzewiacz's answer I believe this will break your system.